# Change origin of node in SceneKit Interface Builder

Tags: interface-builder, scenekit

Does anyone know how to change the origin of a node in SceneKit Interface Builder? The origin is incorrect, but moving it simply moves the model, I want to move the origin so it's in the middle of the object :-/

Maybe I need to re-export my model with a different origin?

[image: Object origin]

Comment: *Maybe I need to re-export my model with a different origin?* FYI, I would urge you to redo the model with the desired pivot (and indeed, with z-forward). It's an incredibly common minor mistake in 3d/game development, that studio makes a model with the pivot in the wrong place! In 100% of cases it's best to just redo the model, in the long run.  Moving the pivot in the 3d engine is a real band-aid that causes trauma later!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reposition the node's `pivot`. For example,

```
    truckNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(13.4, 12.9, 28.9)
```

You can also change rotation of the pivot but it appears you are interested in just the translational aspects which the above example satisfies.

Another option is to make your node a child of an otherwise empty "container node". Reposition your node within the container and then do all subsequent translations and rotations on the container node.

Another option using Interface Builder. Select your dae file. At the bottom of the editor window, on the left, is a square button with a bar on its left. Click it to open the Scene Graph. This will show a hierarchical list of the nodes in your file. In the Utilities panel to the right in your Xcode window, select the "box" icon. You can adjust a nodes position numerically there. You can also drag its axes directly in the editor. But this will not change the pivot which I think is what you want to do. You may have to create a new node to act as a container as mentioned above. This can be done by right-clicking on a node in the Scene Graph to bring up a menu. In my opinion, setting the `pivot` in code is easier. Details below.

BTW, you can get the names of the nodes in your dae scene from the Scene Graph in this editor. Here's how you access dae nodes in code:

```
    guard let theTruck = SCNScene(named: "myTruck") else {
        print("Couldn't find molecule in dictionary  (myTruck)")
        return  }

    let truck = theTruck.rootNode.childNodeWithName("truckBase", recursively: true)!
    truck.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(12.0, 0, 8.0)
```

In this example: "myTruck" is the name of your dae file without the dae suffix. "truckBase" is the name of your root node within the dae file (you can change the name in the editor Scene Graph if desired). "truck" is a new node to which you've assigned the root node of your file. Manipulate it just as you would, and instead of, the root node of your dae. "theTruck" is a temporary holder for the dae `SCNScene`, used just to access the nodes within. You can access any other nodes in your dae this same way allowing you to manipulate them in code.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes but more problematic. I've elaborated above.

Comment: Used the Node inspector in IB as suggested in the middle, worked great, changed the x Euler to -90 to rotate 90 degress in the desired direction.  Thanks!